# Split string, join another table using elements from split string and sum variable from joined table in R

Tags: r, join, split, sum

I have a list of IDs that I would like to use in a `left_join()` and `summarise()` to get the sum of another value. I can do it with one row but not with multiple.

This works:

```
library(tidyverse)

str_split(c("24,108"), ",") %>% 
  as.data.frame() %>%
  rename_(id = names(.))%>% 
  left_join(barriers_h, by = "id") %>%
  summarise(sum(Pass)) %>%
  pull(1)
```

This doesn't

```
df %>%
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(pathway.pass = if_else(is.na(barrier.id), NA_real_,
                                str_split(barrier.id, ",") %>%
                                  as.data.frame() %>%
                                  rename_(id = names(.)) %>%
                                  left_join(barriers_h, by = "id") %>%
                                  summarise(sum(Pass)) %>%
                                  pull(1)
                                ))
```

and gives the error

```
Error in (function (..., row.names = NULL, check.rows = FALSE, check.names = TRUE,  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 2, 5
```

`df` is

```
          barrier.id pathway.pass
3             24,108      0.25000
4 24,108,167,148,195      0.03125
```

`barrier_h` is

```
   id       Pass
1  24 0.26894142
2 108 0.02931223
3 148 0.07585818
4 167 0.02931223
5 195 0.02931223
```

Desired outcome is

```
          barrier.id pathway.pass
3             24,108      0.26894142
4 24,108,167,148,195      0.1637949
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work?

```
df %>% mutate(ID = row_number()) %>% separate_rows(barrier.id) %>% type.convert(as.is = T) %>% 
left_join(barrier_h, by = c('barrier.id' = 'id')) %>% select(1,3,4) %>% group_by(ID) %>% 
summarise(barrier.id = toString(barrier.id), Pass = sum(Pass)) %>% rename(pathway.pass = Pass)
`summarise()` ungrouping output (override with `.groups` argument)
# A tibble: 2 x 3
     ID barrier.id             pathway.pass
  <int> <chr>                         <dbl>
1     1 24, 108                       0.298
2     2 24, 108, 167, 148, 195        0.433
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's my attempt:

```
library(data.table)
library(tidyverse)

df <- fread(text="barrier.id pathway.pass
24,108      0.25000
24,108,167,148,195      0.03125")

barrier <- fread(text="id       Pass
24 0.26894142
108 0.02931223
148 0.07585818
167 0.02931223
195 0.02931223")

results <- df %>% 
  mutate(barrier.id = strsplit(barrier.id,","), group = row_number()) %>%
  unnest(barrier.id) %>%
  mutate(barrier.id = as.numeric(barrier.id)) %>%
  left_join(barrier, by = c("barrier.id"="id")) %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  summarize(barrier.id = paste0(barrier.id,collapse=","), pathway.pass = sum(Pass)) 


  group barrier.id         pathway.pass
  <int> <chr>                     <dbl>
1     1 24,108                    0.298
2     2 24,108,167,148,195        0.433
```